# Storage for camera photos under android

Tags: android, photo

Does anyone know how to determine, on an android system, where the camera photos are being stored?  Whats the pathname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

There is `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`. Some camera apps will store photos in there, in directories or subdirectories.

However, there are dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed camera apps across the ~10,000 Android device models. And there are hundreds of additional camera apps available for users to install. The behavior of each will vary.